# How Can I Report Moderation Abuse?

Tags: support, moderation

I asked a WordPress specific question and it is closed suddenly. I would say it's an abuse of the moderator. How can I report it or who should I talk to?

The page is this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63812/does-a-plugin-file-have-to-end-with

Comment: The person in the above comment is the one closed the topic for the biased opinion. It's not tolerable.

Comment: Let me be very clear - this is not moderator abuse. Your question did not (and still does not) appear to be on-topic for this site because it's dealing with a standard PHP error and standard PHP tags (not WordPress specific). In the future, should you disagree with closure you should **edit your question** to address the critique and **nominate it for reopening** afterwards. If you can't click reopen, merely editing and leaving a comment is often enough.

Comment: The question is clearly on topic. Enclosing with `?>` is talked about in many WordPress support pages and it seems to be a requirement for many WordPress theme and plugin files although PHP files in general can end with HTML code. Plus wp-config-sample.php even does not end with `?>` which is really confusing for many WordPress users. Anyway, thanks for re-opening the question.

Comment: I have found that some here are much quicker to criticize than help, and it is very discouraging when you have a difficult problem in what to you looks just like Wordpress development. I have had very similar negative experiences here recently.

Comment: @Sinthia V please study FAQ and especially [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) to get the best value and experience using the site. I know it can hit hard when your question is rapidly shot down, however there is nothing mean or personal about it. This is how system works and how people contributing their free time to it [barely] manage to prune the site and uphold its rules.

Comment: @Rarst I got most of my cred from editing first-time low-quality posts on SO. I do Chinese android, Russian c++, whatever. Grammar and spelling. I don't like the tone here. This site is harsh. I find it far less friendly and helpful than SO. If you aren't interested in a question, fine but I see active topics that I am interested in being shut down. Why vote down so much? Other sites on the exchange don't. All my questions here do. I wonder when these people get time to write any code? In other words, why shout me down? Why not let every question be answered if someone wants to answer?

Comment: May I note that all moderators where nominated for and voted for by the community itself, if a corrupt moderator is in power the community put it there. Perhaps it would be a good idea to exercise the right to vote in future, or just ask general PHP questions on SO, rather than the WP specific site

Comment: @SinthiaV I couldn't agree more. I just had a question closed because it was php specific when I was asking what php syntax I should use so that it would work in most _WordPress_ installations. That really is a question about _WordPress_ and, unfortunately, I don't have enough karma on this site to even ask to reopen it. Plus, if people wanted to be helpful and not just putative, they could move php specific questions to stack overflow. I know that means implementing an entirely new feature but it would make the site feel a lot less snarky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think your question was closed for invalid reason, than there's a tool for that: `reopen`.

> [image: left hand link "reopen"]

<sup>left hand side</sup>

Another option would be to read through the [FAQ](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) to see what's »on topic«.

About the official WP.org forum: This is a conventional forum, where not all tools that are present here can be used there too. So close voting isn't possible.

The last option you have is to »flag« the question and request a move to SO, where this is more on topic than here, where we deal with wp only questions.

Last but not least: Don't take it personal - this happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. I don't find the reopen link though.

Comment: @Teno It seems that this will only come with some reputation points. You need to answer some questions, participate in the network and learn things (like this one right now) to get all the privileges. Just don't be shy: participate ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how your question is specific to WordPress. Both the handling PHP tags and issues unwanted whitespace can cause are generic issues.

> How can I report it or who should I talk to?

In a sense you already did by posting here. If you want to contact higher powers directly/privately there is always [*contact us*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) link in footer with directions including [help > question closed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/closed) section.

Comment: okey, I sent a message via the contact form. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What the question in question is asking is if it is required to close the last PHP tag used in a PHP file, and that is not a question specific for WordPress. The answer doesn't change if, instead of WordPress, you are using plain PHP, Joomla, Zend Framework, or Drupal. In fact, it is a question about PHP, not WordPress.

> I would say it's an abuse of the moderator.

Moderators close questions that are blatantly off-topic, not constructive, not real questions. If the community around the site thinks the question has been wrongly closed, the users who can vote to re-open it (including the OP) vote to re-open the question.

> How can I report it or who should I talk to?

You can report it here, as you did, if you think the question has been wrongly closed. In this way, you catch the attention of those users who can vote to re-open it.

The other alternative is using the "contact us" link visible at the bottom of every page, but I would not use it just because you want your question re-opened. The community around a Stack Exchange site can better decide if a question is off-topic, or not; Community Coordinators don't generally know much about the topic of a site to be able to decide when a question is appropriate for a site, except in the generic cases (e.g. shopping recommendation sites).
I would use the "contact us" link if you have any reason to think a moderator is abusing his power, which (of course) doesn't mean closing a question over X you asked.